# PySpark set local dir to avoid java.io.IOException: No space left on device

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

`Spark` is throwing the error `java.io.IOException: No space left on device` which I have traced to the overflow of the directory `/tmp` where `Spark` is creating temporary files.  I want to manually specify another location for these files where more space is available.  Currently using `PySpark 3.1.2` on `Ubuntu 20.04`.  Have tried the following already without success (`Spark` still writes to `/tmp`):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set('spark.local.dirs', '/home/tmp')
```

have also tried instead

```
spark.conf.set('spark.local.dir', '/home/tmp')
```

In both cases `Spark` is ignoring the configuration change to write to another dir (`/home/tmp`) and instead is writing to the default dir as if no configuration change (`/tmp`) where there is not sufficient space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it from inside the spark session - since the Spark session was already created, so the local dir was already set (and used). You should pass it as parameter when starting:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.config('spark.local.dir', '/home/tmp').getOrCreate()
```

Comment: Regarding the proposed solution, ```PySpark``` is creating this in response ```WARN SparkConf: Note that spark.local.dir will be overridden by the value set by the cluster manager (via SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS in mesos/standalone/kubernetes and LOCAL_DIRS in YARN).```

Comment: A solution I finally found is to set ```SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS``` as a system environment variable with no additional configuration required for the ```SparkSession``` object.

Comment: Both methods can achieve the goal. SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS for all sessions. SparkSession.builder.config is for a single session, and the warning can be safely ignored.